# OpenCL invalid command queue error when copying from private memory to global

Tags: opencl

I am trying to fix an error in the program and I pinpointed it to the really small area.

Whenever I am trying to copy data from private memory of the device into the global memory, command queue gets invalidated, and clFinish() returns an error.

Consider a simple example:

```
kernel void example(global int *data, const int width) {
    int id = get_global_id(0);

    if (id == 0) {
        int copy[width]; // private memory?
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            copy[i] = data[i]; // works
            data[i] = copy[i]; // works
        }

        // whenever this loop is here
        // i get invalid command queue from clFinish
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            data[i] = copy[i];
        }
    }
}
```

So can somebody explain to me why is that the reason?

Thank you

Comment: The second statement in the first loop and the statement in the second loop basically do the same thing. Why?. I'm thinking the compiler has some role to play here. What card are you using? NVIDIA or AMD?. You can have a look at PTX (if NVIDIA) to see whether it represents the same code

Comment: Trying to compile the kernel brings up: `error: openCL does not support variable length arrays
        int copy[width];`

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not supported per the spec.  In the 1.2 spec, you can find this in Section 6.9 d.

Answer (score 3):

If the width does exceed the maximum size, the private memory will be fine. I recommend you to run the kernel with **width=8/16**, for example, and see the result.  If you used to pass a large value for width. It might not be possible to hold all data in the private memory. They are registers and have very limited size.